# Is passing a method (that returns a value) as a parameter a bad thing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, parameters

So for instance I have this method: `LoadFunkyInfo(byval funkyData as string)` And I pass it something like this: `LoadFunkyInfo(giantTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("blahName"))`. Should I do this instead?

```
dim foo as string = giantTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("blahName")
LoadFunkyInfo(foo)
```

I read somewhere long ago, that it's better to assign the method to a variable and pass that variable to a method, as opposed to passing the method as a parameter. Is that still true? Or true at all?

Note: I'm using VB.Net 3.5

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing a *method*, you are passing the result of calling a method. The only advantage of introducing a temp variable there is to help you debug: if you put a breakpoint on the second line, you'll be able to see the value you're passing to `LoadFunkyInfo`. Other than that, the two invocations are identical.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're not passing a method as a parameter. You're passing the value returned from a method as a parameter.

Second, it's mostly a matter of readability. I personally find it more readable to assign the value to a variable first in most cases.

Comment: Precisely, readability is a big factor here. Don't understand why no one gave you +1. Fixed :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure my title already states what you found, unknowingly, necessary to emphasize. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Doing the latter (assigning to an interim variable) aids with debugging.

It lets you set a breakpoint on the assignment and see the results.

Some compilers will translate the version with the interim variable to the one without when building with certain optimization flags (say Release instead of Debug).

The value that gets passed through is not the method - it is the value *returned* from the method, just as happens with the interim variable - it gets assigned the valued returned and then that value gets passed on as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it mostly depends on the fact if you want to use the data returned by the first function multiple times. For example if you have something like this:

```
LoadFunkyInfo(giantTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("blahName"))
LoadOtherFunkyInfo(giantTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("blahName"))
```

Then it is better to store the returned value instead of calling the method twice:

```
dim foo as string = giantTable.Rows.Item(0).Item("blahName")
LoadFunkyInfo(foo)
LoadOtherFunkyInfo(foo)
```

Otherwise there is no need to store the value.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of taste and what you think ease easiest to read.  Compiles to exactly the same code.  For the example given I would prefer not seeing the transient variable 'foo' and generally defining variables just to pass them in the next statement is going to be unsightly.  However, is the function call has a lot of parameters and the parameters are other function that have long names then that too can get hard to read.

I would say only use it when it removes ambiguity from the code.